# Конструктор операций над классом не конструирует

Tags: python

Есть класс двухмерного вектора.

```
class vec(object):

    def __init__(self, x=int(), y=int()):

        self.x=x
        self.y=y
```

Требуется объявить методы операций с классом ( vec + vec, -, *, /, //, ...)

```
...
    def __add__(self, vector):

        return self.__class__(self.x + vector.x, self.y + vector.y)
...
```

Все они отличаются только именем метода и двумя одинаковыми символами. От этой мысли я начал думать над конструктором этих методов.

В целом все мои варианты не отличались от этого:

```
...
    def __math__(self, vector, operation):

        return eval(f"self.__class__(self.x {operation} vector.x, self.y {operation} vector.y)")

    def __init__(self, x=int(), self.y=int()):

        ...
        for attr, operation in (("add", '+'), ):

            setattr(self, f"__{attr}__", lambda self, vector: self.__math__(vector, operation)
...
```

По моему взгляду конструктор должен успешно добавить все методы корректно. Никаких ошибок до операций не возникает, но после оказывается, что конструктор ничерта не конструировал:

```
>>> vec(5, 5) + vec(2, 15)

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'vec' and 'vec'
```

В чем его проблема? Может знаете как сделать конструктор лучше?

---

Интересный тест:

```
class vec(object):

    def __math__(self, vector, operation):

        return eval(f"self.__class__(self.x {operation} vector.x, self.y {operation} vector.y)")

    def __init__(self, x=int(), y=int()):

        self.x=x
        self.y=y

        for name, operation in (("add", '+'), ):

            setattr(self, f"__{name}__", lambda self, vector: self.__math__(vector, operation))

if __name__ != "__main__":

    try:

        vec(100, 500) + vec(900, 500)

    except TypeError:

        print("Failed\n", dir(vec()), '\n\n')
```

Импортируйте в терминале библиотеку с этим тестом. Результат:

```
>>> import muz
Failed
 ['__add__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__math__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'x', 'y']

>>>  muz.vec().__add__(muz.vec(7, 6), muz.vec(5, 2))
<muz.vec object at 0x00E3BB50>
```

То есть внимание на "Failed": операция сложения vec + vec невозможна. Следом печатаем список атрибутов класса вектора. Внимание на первых элемент списка аттрибутов: `__add__` имеется. Казалось бы, в чем твоя проблема, блин? Вызвать `__add__` мне удалось только каким то ломаным способом (вторая строка снизу).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Методы объекта необходимо создавать на этапе создания объекта (метод `__new__`). В `__init__` же происходит уже инициализация.

```
from itertools import starmap

class Vector:

    @classmethod
    def method_factory(cls, name):
        assert hasattr(int, name), f'{name} not a method int'
        def method(a, b):
            return cls(*starmap(lambda x, y: getattr(x, name)(y), zip(a, b)))
        return method

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):

        methods = "__add__", "__sub__", "__mul__"  # добавить другие
        for m in methods:
            setattr(cls, m, cls.method_factory(m))

        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __iter__(self):
        # для упаковки в zip
        yield from (self.x, self.y)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Vector: x = {self.x}, y = {self.y}'


v1 = Vector(1, 2)
v2 = Vector(2, 5)


print(v1 + v2)  # Vector: x = 3, y = 7
print(v1 - v2)  # Vector: x = -1, y = -3
print(v1 * v2)  # Vector: x = 2, y = 10
```